# Using a collection-repeat with ion-side-menus

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use a collection-repeat list in an app which uses ion-side-menus. When I don't use menus, the collection-repeat seems to work. When I do use menus, the collection-repeat doesn't display anything on the screen (although I can see the items it's adding to the page in browser dev tools).

Are these two ionic elements incompatible with each other?

Here are two examples:

**Without ion-side-menus (working)**

```
<html ng-app="contactsApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Collection-Repeat: Early Preview</title>

  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .list .my-item.item {
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">3000 Contacts</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list">
      <a class="item my-item"
        collection-repeat="item in contacts"
        collection-item-height="getItemHeight(item)"
        collection-item-width="'100%'"
        ng-href="https://www.google.com/#q={{item.first_name + '+' + item.last_name}}"
        ng-style="{'line-height': getItemHeight(item) + 'px'}">
        {{item.letter || (item.first_name+' '+item.last_name)}}
      </a>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    angular.module('contactsApp', ['ionic'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicScrollDelegate, filterFilter) {
      $scope.contacts = window.CONTACTS;
      $scope.getItemHeight = function(item) { return 100; };
    });

    window.CONTACTS = [{"id":1,"first_name":"Patrick","last_name":"Rogers","country":"Cyprus","ip_address":"153.88.89.148","email":"progers@yata.net"},
    {"id":2,"first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Gordon","country":"Croatia","ip_address":"209.73.121.212","email":"jgordon@skivee.biz"},
    {"id":3,"first_name":"Kathy","last_name":"Hamilton","country":"Armenia","ip_address":"164.214.217.162","email":"khamilton@rhynyx.biz"},
    {"id":4,"first_name":"Stephanie","last_name":"Johnson","country":"Mauritius","ip_address":"8.199.242.67","email":"sjohnson@jabbertype.mil"},
    {"id":5,"first_name":"Jerry","last_name":"Palmer","country":"Thailand","ip_address":"230.207.100.163","email":"jpalmer@avamm.org"},
    {"id":6,"first_name":"Lillian","last_name":"Franklin","country":"Germany","ip_address":"150.190.116.1","email":"lfranklin@eare.mil"},
    {"id":7,"first_name":"Melissa","last_name":"Gordon","country":"Serbia","ip_address":"162.156.29.99","email":"mgordon@flashset.org"},
    {"id":8,"first_name":"Sarah","last_name":"Burns","country":"Grenada","ip_address":"13.177.156.223","email":"sburns@eimbee.info"},
    {"id":9,"first_name":"Willie","last_name":"Burton","country":"Croatia","ip_address":"115.133.81.82","email":"wburton@dynazzy.info"},
    {"id":10,"first_name":"Tina","last_name":"Simmons","country":"United States Virgin Islands","ip_address":"113.49.63.18","email":"tsimmons@devpulse.mil"},
    {"id":11,"first_name":"Kenneth","last_name":"Larson","country":"Mexico","ip_address":"92.89.76.196","email":"klarson@browseblab.info"},
    {"id":12,"first_name":"Philip","last_name":"Welch","country":"Cuba","ip_address":"223.180.48.70","email":"pwelch@skippad.edu"},
    {"id":13,"first_name":"Nicholas","last_name":"Parker","country":"British Indian Ocean Territory","ip_address":"200.150.119.13","email":"nparker@twitternation.net"},
    {"id":14,"first_name":"Nicole","last_name":"Webb","country":"Moldova","ip_address":"47.66.237.205","email":"nwebb@midel.biz"},
    {"id":15,"first_name":"Clarence","last_name":"Schmidt","country":"China","ip_address":"134.84.246.67","email":"cschmidt@dazzlesphere.net"},
    {"id":16,"first_name":"Jessica","last_name":"Murray","country":"Sao Tome and Principe","ip_address":"211.30.32.109","email":"jmurray@jumpxs.net"},
    {"id":17,"first_name":"Willie","last_name":"Schmidt","country":"US Minor Outlying Islands","ip_address":"158.40.109.208","email":"wschmidt@babbleset.edu"},
    {"id":18,"first_name":"Margaret","last_name":"Evans","country":"Bhutan","ip_address":"252.123.77.101","email":"mevans@voolia.info"},
    {"id":19,"first_name":"Arthur","last_name":"Morales","country":"Faroe Islands","ip_address":"116.5.126.29","email":"amorales@brainlounge.biz"},
    {"id":20,"first_name":"Charles","last_name":"Perez","country":"Italy","ip_address":"10.43.255.4","email":"cperez@avaveo.net"}];
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**With ion-side-menus (not working)**

```
<html ng-app="contactsApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Collection-Repeat: Early Preview</title>

  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      .list .my-item.item {
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ion-nav-view>
    <ion-side-menus>
      <!-- Center content -->
      <ion-side-menu-content ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      </ion-side-menu-content>

      <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">3000 Contacts</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
          <a class="item my-item"
            collection-repeat="item in contacts"
            collection-item-height="getItemHeight(item)"
            collection-item-width="'100%'"
            ng-href="https://www.google.com/#q={{item.first_name + '+' + item.last_name}}"
            ng-style="{'line-height': getItemHeight(item) + 'px'}">
            {{item.letter || (item.first_name+' '+item.last_name)}}
          </a>
        </div>
      </ion-content>

      <!-- Left menu -->
      <ion-side-menu side="left">
        This is the side menu.
      </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
  </ion-nav-view>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    angular.module('contactsApp', ['ionic'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicScrollDelegate, filterFilter) {
      $scope.contacts = window.CONTACTS;
      $scope.getItemHeight = function(item) { return 100; };
    });

    window.CONTACTS = [{"id":1,"first_name":"Patrick","last_name":"Rogers","country":"Cyprus","ip_address":"153.88.89.148","email":"progers@yata.net"},
    {"id":2,"first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Gordon","country":"Croatia","ip_address":"209.73.121.212","email":"jgordon@skivee.biz"},
    {"id":3,"first_name":"Kathy","last_name":"Hamilton","country":"Armenia","ip_address":"164.214.217.162","email":"khamilton@rhynyx.biz"},
    {"id":4,"first_name":"Stephanie","last_name":"Johnson","country":"Mauritius","ip_address":"8.199.242.67","email":"sjohnson@jabbertype.mil"},
    {"id":5,"first_name":"Jerry","last_name":"Palmer","country":"Thailand","ip_address":"230.207.100.163","email":"jpalmer@avamm.org"},
    {"id":6,"first_name":"Lillian","last_name":"Franklin","country":"Germany","ip_address":"150.190.116.1","email":"lfranklin@eare.mil"},
    {"id":7,"first_name":"Melissa","last_name":"Gordon","country":"Serbia","ip_address":"162.156.29.99","email":"mgordon@flashset.org"},
    {"id":8,"first_name":"Sarah","last_name":"Burns","country":"Grenada","ip_address":"13.177.156.223","email":"sburns@eimbee.info"},
    {"id":9,"first_name":"Willie","last_name":"Burton","country":"Croatia","ip_address":"115.133.81.82","email":"wburton@dynazzy.info"},
    {"id":10,"first_name":"Tina","last_name":"Simmons","country":"United States Virgin Islands","ip_address":"113.49.63.18","email":"tsimmons@devpulse.mil"},
    {"id":11,"first_name":"Kenneth","last_name":"Larson","country":"Mexico","ip_address":"92.89.76.196","email":"klarson@browseblab.info"},
    {"id":12,"first_name":"Philip","last_name":"Welch","country":"Cuba","ip_address":"223.180.48.70","email":"pwelch@skippad.edu"},
    {"id":13,"first_name":"Nicholas","last_name":"Parker","country":"British Indian Ocean Territory","ip_address":"200.150.119.13","email":"nparker@twitternation.net"},
    {"id":14,"first_name":"Nicole","last_name":"Webb","country":"Moldova","ip_address":"47.66.237.205","email":"nwebb@midel.biz"},
    {"id":15,"first_name":"Clarence","last_name":"Schmidt","country":"China","ip_address":"134.84.246.67","email":"cschmidt@dazzlesphere.net"},
    {"id":16,"first_name":"Jessica","last_name":"Murray","country":"Sao Tome and Principe","ip_address":"211.30.32.109","email":"jmurray@jumpxs.net"},
    {"id":17,"first_name":"Willie","last_name":"Schmidt","country":"US Minor Outlying Islands","ip_address":"158.40.109.208","email":"wschmidt@babbleset.edu"},
    {"id":18,"first_name":"Margaret","last_name":"Evans","country":"Bhutan","ip_address":"252.123.77.101","email":"mevans@voolia.info"},
    {"id":19,"first_name":"Arthur","last_name":"Morales","country":"Faroe Islands","ip_address":"116.5.126.29","email":"amorales@brainlounge.biz"},
    {"id":20,"first_name":"Charles","last_name":"Perez","country":"Italy","ip_address":"10.43.255.4","email":"cperez@avaveo.net"}];
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a Codepen of your issue? PS.: I can't see difference between your two examples...

Comment: Arugh. While looking at the code for the second block, I found the issue; I pasted the template outside the ion-side-menu-content tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the list content is visible in the second example because there's nothing in the `ion-side-menu-content` tag. When the `ion-header-bar` and `ion-content` tags and their content are moved into the `ion-side-menu-content` tag, the second example works.